# ng-controller does not properly evaluate expression

Tags: angularjs

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app lang="de">
<head>
    <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="angular-locale_de-de.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function CostCtrl($scope){
            $scope.cost = 1;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>
            <label for="cost">Nettobetrag</label>
            <input type="text" name="cost" ng-model="cost" autofocus>
        </p>
        <p>Nettobetrag {{cost|currency}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller in head is yet without function, for now it works as it should. In the input field you put a number and below this number formatted as currency (german) appears.

When I add a `ng-controller="CostCtrl"` in body, like described in the video the output is the unrendered `{{cost|currency}}`.

Does that all mean i can't put my angular-script inline? Is this a version conflict? I'm using Angularjs 1.4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your controller with the angular module that is being bootstrapped.

First, make an angular module that you use to instantiate your application:

```
var mod = angular.module('myModule', []);
```

Then, make sure your page is bootstrapped to include this module

```
<html ng-app="myModule" lang="de">
```

Once you have designed your controller, include it in the module

```
mod.controller('CostCtrl', CostCtrl);
```

Angular does not automatically search the global namespace to find your functions. You must register them explicitly.

You can read more in the [angular ng-app reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).

Besides not instantiating the module, your code looks fine.

Comment: I tried it this way:
`<script>
            var mod = angular.module('myModule');
            mod.controller('CostCtrl', CostCtrl);
            function CostCtrl($scope){
                $scope.cost = 1;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="CostCtrl">` but still unrendered. Still in video it was shown the first way I tried it. Its from packtpub. Can you tell me the right way to do it?

Comment: I mistyped the `angular.module` call. It should be `angular.module('myModule', [])`. See [my jsbin](http://jsbin.com/feteyudopi)

Comment: Cooooool, it works! But I still wonder why in the video it was taught the wrong way. Might that depend on the versionchange over the Time, so that the way in the video formerly worked?

Comment: I'm not sure why your video does not tell the correct answer. I'd recommend using the angular documentation, as its tutorial is comprehensive and easy to follow.

Comment: Ahhh, I found out with version 1.2.17 the first try worked. With 1.4.7 it doesn't. By the way, I haven't said thank you... So many thanks to you, mr. Stikeskids!